# unable to start nginx on ubuntu12.04 (precise) with rstudio

Tags: r, nginx, rstudio

I am running a remote server on EC2 with rstudio and was looking to set up a reverse proxy as indicated in the documentation [here](http://support.rstudio.org/help/kb/rstudio-server/running-with-a-proxy) using nginx

When I start or restart nginx i get the error message shown below. Obviously, nothing else is running on port 80. I dont have apache or any other webserver installed.

```
ubuntu@ip-10-4-xxx-xxx:~$ sudo fuser -k 80/tcp ; sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
nginx.
```

the module I added to ngnix.conf is the recommended snippet:

```
http {
  server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8787;
      proxy_redirect http://localhost:8787/ $scheme://$host/;
    }
  }
}
```

I did try using 8080 instead of 80 and ngnix starts fine, but doesn't connect to rstudio. rstudio is meanwhile available on 8787. It feels like i am missing something really simple here. Help please!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aww snap.. Just got it after typing up the question in full. The conf file had an include that had to be commented out

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

changed to

```
#include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

Works perfectly now. Somebody @rstudio please update the documentation in the link I showed above

UPDATE: Please see the response from @DirkEddelbuettel in his comment below. The right way would be to add this code snippet in an appropriate file in the "sites-enabled" directory.

Comment: I think you are doing this wrong -- I think your added config should be in a file in that 'sites-enabled' subdir.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel you are right. Should be in the enabled sites folder. Updating my answer.